# How To Check If Element Is Visible In Web Browser In VB.net?

Tags: .net, vb.net, dom, browser

I want to check if an element is visible (i.e. has not set to display: none, visibility: hidden) in browser element but IN VB.Net

How can I do that? I googled but didn't found anything, not even in official documents.

The element is like:

```
<div id="elem">
<a href="DYNAMIC LINK">Link</a>
<a href="DYNAMIC LINK">Link</a>
<a href="DYNAMIC LINK">Link</a>
</div>
```

And now I want to select 2nd  tag, and check if its visible. My questions:

1. How do I check if second  exists?
2. How do I select second  tag above?
3. How do I check if its visible

I tried:

```
If (downloadSite.Document.GetElementById("elem").GetElementsByTagName("a")[1] IsNot Nothing) 
' Working
End If
```

But it doesn't work.

Comment: Shall an element in invisible there should be some kind of css properties set on that element. If its a server side control you can get a reference to that control in code behind and check for css class

Comment: Please check. Updated.

Comment: I think your syntax in the if statement is wrong. It should be:
`If Not downloadSite.Document.GetElementById("elem").GetElementsByTagName("a")(1) Is Nothing Then`
That will get you the element if it exists, however getting to its style will be tough. It will be even tougher if you are looking for its computed style, as this may be affected by client side scripting that does not trigger any events on the web broser control.